# WebLogic (with SSL) as proxy for any WSGI web server

Tags: ssl, nginx, weblogic, wsgi

I researched about any plugin/module WSGI for Oracle WebLogic 12c that allows me run a python flask app, with no success.

The reason for why i need to run from WebLogic 12c, it's because i need to use the SSL certfied living there.

Researching, i found many web server (Apache, Gunicorn, etc) can act as proxy of WebLogic, here is an example, where Nginx receive all the requests with SSL and then passed them to WebLogic:

https://medium.com/@Dracontis/nginx-as-proxy-for-weblogic-with-ssl-c7e1076e2c0c

So, i wonder if there is a manner to invert this order? I mean, WebLogic receive all the requests (safely because of SSL certified) and then pass them to any web server with the WSGI standard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a sort of solution that accomplished the topic above. However, in case someone needs implements this topology here is what i did:

I've installed an Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) and creating a wallet for the SSL certified, in certain way in which the OHS can receive the requests secure, then inside the OHS with specific setting achieve forward the request to the Apache running with the module WSGI.